# Get state of checkbox in Node Js server

Tags: node.js

I have a form on the client side where the user can update some information about an ingredient, of which whether the ingredient is in stock(in which case a checkbox is checked) or out of stock(in which case the same checkbox as before is unchecked).

Here's the form:

```
<form action="/inventory/<%=ingredient._id%>?_method=PUT" method="POST" class="form">
        <!-- <form class="formNew form" action="/inventory/<%=ingredient._id%>" method="POST" > -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Ingredient's picture:</label>
                <input type="text" name="item[photoName]"  value="<%=ingredient.photoName%>" class="form-control">
            </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label>Name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="item[name]" value="<%=ingredient.name%>" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Number of items:</label>
            <input type="number" name="item[number]" value="<%=ingredient.number%>" class="form-control" min="0">
          </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <div class="text-center"><label>Or check ingredient item:</label></div>

            <%if(ingredient.exist){%>
                <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="item[checkbox]" checked>
            <% } else { %>
                    <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="item[checkbox]" unchecked>
            <% } %>

          </div>                        
          <button class="text-center btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit">Save changes</button>
      </form>
```

And here's my post route (Node Js) that handles the update:

// update route

```
app.put("/inventory/:id", function(req, res){
 function(err, updatedIngredient){

        var ingredientUpdated={
            photoName:req.body.item["photoName"],
            name:req.body.item["name"],
            number:req.body.item["number"],
            exist:req.body.item["checkbox"].checked         
        }

       Ingredient.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, ingredientUpdated, {new: true}, function(err, updatedIngredient){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {            
            console.log(updatedIngredient);

            if(req.xhr){
                res.json(updatedIngredient);
            } else {
                req.flash("success", "You successfully updated the Ingredient's info");
                res.redirect("/inventory/" + req.params.id);    
            }           
        }
    })
})
```

And finally, here's my Ingredient's schema model (mongoDb/mongoose):

```
var IngredientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    number:Number,
    exist:Boolean,

    author:{
    id:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'User'
    }, 

    username:String
    },

    photoName:String
})
```

However, my implementation doesn't work and I get the error:" Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined"

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I kinda found the solution by accident. I replaced "exist:req.body.item["checkbox"].checked  " with "exist:req.body.item["checkbox"]". Just removed .checked .